# change curser color according to selected language

Tags: macos, mac, settings

I'm sure there are a lot of users who type in their native language + english. 
After they type a sentence, they realize they typed in the wrong language.

`Is there a way to change the curser color to match the currently selected language?`

Comment: Most probably possible.. and cumbersome. What you could do instead is go to _System Preferences_ → _Keyboard_ → _Input Sources_ → check _Show Input menu in menu bar_. That will either show a flag (if the language is county specific e.g. English U.S.) or a letter of the script (e.g. A or א).

Comment: I already do that, but a better UX would be not to pick up your look every time